# SQL generated by LINQ is sometimes "corrupted" on my computer

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, syntax

Ok everyone, this one is weird and I found absolutely nothing on the Internet.

In our application we use Linq, for some reason, on my computer only, if I run the SAME LINQ a couple times, it will sometime fails for syntax errors, invalid columns names, and stuff like that. It seems that sometimes, some weird characters are inserted in the SQL that is generated.

example of error I got :

**Incorrect syntax near ''.**
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Hell sometimes I even get chinese characters in there :

**Incorrect syntax near 'OR抂暙ᚻ'.**

I know this is vague, but I'm the only one in the company getting this right now and it sucks when you try to debug stuff. What could affect the generated SQL like this ?

If anyone as an idea let me know :)

Comment: And it works fine on other computers ? Cause if so, the problem is related to your computer, it could be a wrong version of sql instaled, corrupted files, problem during instalation of a component... it could be hard to find.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yeah, it works every time with other computers, while on mine it works, I would say 85% of the time. I really don't get why the generated SQL is not always the same. If I could avoid formatting my PC I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Exept uninstaling everything related to SQL and Entity-Framework, and reinstaling all... And even if you do that it might still not work... good luck with that

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Thanks! I'll give this thread a day, in case someone faced something similar in the past, then I'll start uninstalling/installing.

Comment: Hardware problems are one of the last things I usually consider when diagnosing a bug, but this one sounds like a candidate. RAM errors can cause this sort of random-looking behavior. Find a memory test tool (e.g. http://www.memtest.org/) and run it overnight. If there *is* a problem, you shouldn't trust the system anymore. Replace the bad memory, wipe the disk, and install fresh.

Comment: @DanM Thanks I will definitely try this out.

Comment: A couple of generic fixes, assuming you are using Visual Studio 2015: delete your solution's `.suo` file (you can find it in your solution folder, as a hidden file, so make sure you change the folder view options to show hidden files); clean your Visual Studio cache (usually you can find it at %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache); if you have ASP.NET projects, delete your temporary ASP files cache (%temp%\Temporary ASP.NET Files). Also, do a Clean of your solution.

Comment: So I tried memtest, didn't find anything. I also did a complete reset of Windows 10, didn't sove the issue either. I'm kind of lost with this one, next step will be a complete format of my laptop I guess.